# Ajax loading screen not showing after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using AJAX to call a servlet from my webpage. So far so good, I have added some code to show a loading screen while the servlet is working but that works only the first time, after that, the servlet is called and I can change the cursor but the waiting screen is not working

CSS

```
#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    z-index: 3000;
    display:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #loading-img {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #297bda;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding: 2rem;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div id="loading">
  <div id="loading-img"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#compare').click(function() {
//just the relevant part

  $('#loading').show();
....
});
```

I am calling to

```
$('#loading').hide();
```

in the .done(function (data).

As I said, the code is executed but the loading screen only loads the first time. In fact, the second time and further I am receiving null when trying to resolve the loading div.
I have also tried with

```
       document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
       document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
```

Instead of using the hide() but the same result.

Any idea?

Comment: Don you want it to work `on loading` ?

Comment: perhaps loading div is not in DOM  at the time it was not working. Did you verify the source of your html whether loading div is available or not when it was not working.

Comment: I tried also to add this in the document ready
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
     $('#loading').hide();
  });

  $(document).ajaxStart(functio0n () {
     $('#loading').show();
  });
But again is just working the first time.
I have tried to remove all the hide/show and just check if I can get the div, again is only being returned the first time....but I am not doing anything for removing it in the ajax call

Comment: Loading probably never fires since the content is cached after the first load...

Answer (score 0):

Found it! after hours, it was my stupid mistake. 
I got this

```
<div id="finalresults">
<div>

<div id="loading">
  <div id="loading-img"></div>
</div>
```

and was doing 
document.getElementById("finalresults").innerHTML = "";
During the ajax call, so I was deleting the loading div bercause I forgot the / in the previous div

Thanks everyone and really sorry for the mistake